# filtering a queryset, applying more than one filter

Tags: django, django-queryset

My models are:

```
models.User:
       id = pk
       username = text

    models.Offer
       id = pk           
       description = text
       publicationDate = Date
       user = Fk(User)

    my serializer is:

    class UserOfferSerializer(ModelSerializer):
        offers = OfferSerializerAll(many=True, read_only=True)
        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ('id', 'username', 'offers')
```

I am trying to apply more than one filter on the queryset:

```
users = users.filter(offers__publicationDate__range=[startdate, enddate]). prefetch_related(Prefetch('offers', queryset=Offer.objects.filter(
publicationDate__range=[startdate, enddate]))).distinct()
```

then

```
users = users.filter(offers__description__icontains=sometext).prefetch_related(Prefetch('offers', queryset=Offer.objects.filter(description__icontains=sometext))).distinct()
```

First one works fine and the other one throws the following exception:

```
ValueError: 'offers' lookup was already seen with a different queryset. You may need to adjust the ordering of your lookups.
```

**Update:**

My current code is:

```
    if (offerBeginDate != None and offerEndDate != None):
        b = offerBeginDate.split('-')
        e = offerEndDate.split('-')

        startdate = datetime.date(int(b[0]), int(b[1]), int(b[2]))
        enddate = datetime.date(int(e[0]), int(e[1]), int(e[2]))

        users = users.filter(offers__publicationDate__range=[startdate, enddate])
        offers = offers.filter(publicationDate__range=[startdate, enddate])

    if (descriptionText != None):

        users = users.filter(offers__functionDescription__icontains=descriptionText.strip())
        offers = offers.filter(functionDescription__icontains=descriptionText.strip())


    users = users.prefetch_related('offers', Prefetch(queryset=offers))
```

Any help? Thank you all :)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `to_attr` argument of `Prefetch` object to prefetch additional queryset:

```
users = users.filter(offers__description__icontains=sometext).prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('offers', queryset=Offer.objects.filter(
publicationDate__range=[startdate, enddate]), to_attr='date_offers'), 
        Prefetch('offers', queryset=Offer.objects.filter(description__icontains=sometext), to_attr='description_offers')).distinct()
```

**UPD**

If you need dynamically add filters to prefetched queryset you can define it separately like this:

```
if some_case:
    users = users.filter(offers__description__icontains=sometext)
    offers=Offer.objects.filter(description__icontains=sometext)
if some_case_2:
    users = users.filter(**conditions)
    offers = offers.filter(**conditions)

users = users.prefetch_related(Prefetch('offers', queryset=offers))
```

Now each user in users queryset will have two attributes: `user.date_offers` and `user.description_offers`.

Comment: Thank you very much :)) I am trying to get it to work but not succeeded yet, I will update soon

Comment: I am also trying to apply the Prefetch on two phases because I don't want always to apply both filters, it depends on the user choice.

Comment: I need to apply in this way: `if(date!=None): apply first filter if(sometext!=None): apply second filter`

Comment: @RodwanBakkar not sure if I understood you right, but check my updated answer:)

Comment: I am trying the updated solution and getting this error `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'lookup''`

Comment: @RodwanBakkar yes it was error in my code. Ive updated answe. Check it.

Comment: still the same!:P

Comment: @RodwanBakkar hm..  can you add to the question you current code?

Comment: each filter is working fine independently but when I joined then using the to_attr I could not get them both to work. now after your last answer the code has no to_attr

Comment: @RodwanBakkar the error in last line of code. "offers" should be inside Prefetch().  It's exactly what I updated after your prevoius comment:)

Comment: yes exactly, sorry, these filters made me stressed that I couldn't see the change, it just worked like a charm, thank you very much man you saved my day :))))))